RAM randomly disappearing on Mac
Since a few weeks, RAM is randomly disappearing from my laptop.
It's a mid-2010 13" MacBook Pro, with 2 slots, each filled with 4 GB of RAM.
So initially, the system indicated 8 GB of RAM.
A few weeks ago, out of nowhere it showed the second slot as empty.
Every time I open it up, take the RAM out and back in, it's back to 8 GB. After some time though, usually a few days but could be during the same day, it goes back to only 4 GB.
I couldn't find any correlation as to when it loses one slot. It seems to be when transporting the laptop, but not always.
I have tried swapping the RAM "cards" (not sure that's the right name in English), to test whether they could be faulty. It's always the same slot going empty, DIMM 1.
I have taken the motherboard out, to see if I could spot something weird, such as a torn connection, or a broken solder. I didn't see anything.
One of the RAM socket's screws was a little bit loose so I tightened it. One of the plastic "springs" that hold the RAM in place also seemed a bit loose, so I wrapped the RAM with adhesive in their sockets, to keep them tight.
We also cleaned inside the RAM slots with an eyeglass cloth.
No change, after a few minutes of use slot 1 appears empty again.
Any idea what could be wrong?
Thanks in advance for the help!

Seems, as you suspect, a hardware issue. Check the connector for bent pins. If you have the equipment, try resoldering the connector pins and the RAM controller, even if there is no macroscopic break: See https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2320986 Of course, resoldering is technically difficult, so you might try putting a piece of plastic foam above the RAM and the controller, to apply gentle pressure when the case is closed, in the hope that might maintain the connection -- for a while.

Thanks a lot for the answer, that's really good to know! I did check visually for bent pins, but couldn't find any. I am wondering whether I am not misunderstanding something, when you say "resoldering the connector pins and the RAM controller". Isn't there just only one thing I could resolder, which would be the feet of the RAM "slots" on the motherboard?

I have a soldering iron, but I am guessing that would be too big. I do have soldering paste though, i could apply some against each foot, and then use a hairdryer?

Thanks again very much for the help!
